# How do I use JQuery to detect if a file input is isset like php

Tags: jquery, html

in php if i use Example

```
if (!empty(the input file)){
//is isset 
}
```

how can i do this in JQuery

html :

```
<div id="trash1">
Clear image
<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
<div id="image-preview">
<input type="file" name="image-upload" id="image-upload">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#trash1").click(function() {

$("#image-upload").val("");

$( "#trash1" ).hide();
$("#image-preview").click(function() {
var file = $("#image-upload").val();
if(file) {
$( "#trash1" ).show();
}else {
$( "#trash1" ).hide();
}
});
});
});
```

I have prepared an example of action here
https://codepen.io/danny2018/pen/RYajPB
When I am loading the file

The div named trash1 need to show if input file is load 
But it only works the second time
Someone might know why this is happening

Comment: i fix it var file = $("#image-upload").val("");

Comment: Please start by indenting your code properly, so that we can easily see what is on which “nesting level” here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var File = document.getElementById("image-upload").files.length;
 if(File > 0){ do stuff.. }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.